# NuGet: Update a package to a specific version in all projects via PowerShell or CMD

Tags: powershell, command-line, nuget

We have a scenario, where different teams work on different parts of a larger product. From time to time, all Visual Studio Projects of all Solutions there need to get some of their referenced NuGet packages updated. As a result of that update, all projects in the whole source tree should reference the same versions of the packages.

Is there a way to update a specific NuGet package to a specific version **in all projects** using some **automatic approach** like **PowerShell** scripts?

Edit:
Is there a way to somehow load the necessary parts of Visual Studio and NuGet to also **update the assembly references correctly**?

Example:

```
NuGetScript Update Solution.sln PackageName -version NewVersion
```

or

```
NuGetScript Update PathToProjects PackageName -version NewVersion
```

There are too many components to load all of them in Visual Studio and update them manually via package manager UI.

Comment: can you give me example about what u want to do ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a PowerShell script to search all the project files or packages.config files in your solution and then call [nuget update](http://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/tools/nuget.exe-cli-reference#update) command to update the packages.

However, there is a limitation when update packages outside of Visual Studio, I would recommend you to do this from Visual Studio:

> The update command will download and extract all new packages to the
>   packages folders. Assembly references will be updated in the project
>   file, however this is limited to only existing references. If a new
>   package has an added assembly it will not be added as part of the
>   update command. New package dependencies will also not have their
>   assembly references added. To perform a complete update use Visual
>   Studio.

Comment: Is this still the ongoing case ? I am trying to do something similar from Azure devops pipeline.

Comment: Looks like you could use the DotNetCLI which doesn't have that problem:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools#feature-availability

Answer (score 30):

Please use following command line in Package Manager Console window to update a specific package in one solution.

> Get-Project -All | Update-Package PackageName -Version newVersion

Comment: This is Package Manager Console command, which need to run in Package Manager Console window in Visual Studio.

Comment: Unless there's a way to load the Package Manager Console without loading Visual Studio and all projects, this can't be the accepted answer.

Comment: dont do this if you have <= 4.71 projects in your solution. It WILL update those as well and bring with it all sorts of nasty dependencies.

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 2):

*The following script was found somewhere else.  I have tried it with my projects.  I don't have the original link*

The following script does:

1. run `restore` command on any solutions found within a folder
2. Finds all `packages.config` files containing the package id name provided
3. runs `update` command using the `packages.config` file and the package name as parameters

This assumes that nuget.exe is present in the folder where you will be running this from

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$packageId
)

Get-ChildItem *.sln -recurse | %{.\\nuget.exe restore $_.fullname}

Get-ChildItem packages.config -Recurse `
  | Where-Object {$_ | Select-String -Pattern $packageId} `
  | %{.\\nuget.exe update -Id $packageId $_.FullName}
```

Comment: Possibly from this - https://thomasardal.com/updating-a-nuget-package-across-multiple-projectssolutions/